# Alternating row colors for groups, on filtered data

Tags: excel, vba

I found a code on this site to change the colors of rows based on changing data in a specific column (so for each set of rows with same data in a column, I want to alternate colors, for better visibility).

I have put this part of code after the auto filter on a specific column, so I want to run my code for the colors only on the filtered (visible) lines (when data in column N changes)

If I run the code now, it does more or less what it needs to do, but as shown in example, the first two visible rows should have a different color, as they have different values compared to the 3rd and 4th rows.

at the bottom of my file it goes wrong again (not shown here), what do I need to change in my code to apply the colors only on the visible lines ?

This is my code

```
    Sub DubbeleOrders()
    
    ' dubbele orders Dim Switch As Boolean
    
     Dim ws As Worksheet    Dim Lastrow As Long
     
     
        Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Page1")).Name = "dubbel"
        
        Set ws = Worksheets("dubbel")
         
        Sheets("Page1").Select
        Range("A9").CurrentRegion.Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("dubbel").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Columns("A:M").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
               ws.Range("N1").Formula = "art/qty/date" ws.Range("O1").Formula = "controle"
       
        
        Lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        
        ws.Range("N2:N" & Lastrow).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-6]&"" "",""QTY ""&RC[-4]&"" "",TEXT(RC[-2],""dd-mm-jj""))"
        ws.Range("O2:O" & Lastrow).Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF(R2C14:R2000C14,RC[-1])=1,0,1)"
    
     Columns("A:M").EntireColumn.AutoFit    Range("A1:O2000").Sort Key1:=Range("N1"), Header:=xlYes
    
      
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1:O2000").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="1"
    
      For Each Cell In Range("N2:N" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
        If Not Cell.Value = Cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then Switch = Not (Switch)
        If Switch Then Range("A" & Cell.Row & ":" & Chr(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 64) & Cell.Row).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        If Not Switch Then Range("A" & Cell.Row & ":" & Chr(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 64) & Cell.Row).Interior.color = 14869218 
      Next
       
         End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Ooops! Yes. Try to add another IF statement inside the FOR loop: `IF  cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then` and before `Next` place `End If`. Maybe it will help in coloring too.

Comment: Thanks Black cat, that does the trick ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Get the visible range (Row) with `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

```
     Dim lastCell, ColCnt As Long, Switch As Boolean
    lastCell = Range("N2").Value
    ColCnt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    Dim visRange As Range
    Set visRange = ActiveSheet.Range("N2:N" & ColCnt).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If Not visRange Is Nothing Then
        For Each Cell In visRange
            If Not Cell.Value = lastCell Then
                Switch = Not (Switch)
                lastCell = Cell.Value
            End If
            If Switch Then
                Cells(Cell.Row, 1).Resize(1, ColCnt).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            Else
                Cells(Cell.Row, 1).Resize(1, ColCnt).Interior.Color = 14869218
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: I seem to get a run time error 1004 : no cells were found, need to investigate why ...

Comment: Which line raises the error?

Comment: For Each cell In Range("N2:N" & ColCnt).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Comment: I have updated code, pls try it.

Comment: It still gave that error, but I got it working when I changed it like this                              '  Set visRange = Worksheets("dubbel").Range("N2:N" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '

Comment: struggling with the layout now, but I hope you understand :) I cannot seem to format the code properly

Comment: If activesheet is NOT `dubble`, the output of your revised code is not reliable. Use use the updated code either in my replay, or `Set visRange = Worksheets("dubbel").Range("N2:N" & Worksheets("dubbel").UsedRange.Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`.

Comment: ok, got it, thanks ! Again a daily task that can get done quicker :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DubbeleOrders()

    ' dubbele
    Dim ws As Worksheet, cell As Range, Lastrow As Long
    Dim prev, bSwitch As Boolean, rng As Range
 
    Set ws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Page1"))
    With ws
        .Name = "dubbel"
        Sheets("Page1").Range("A9").CurrentRegion.Copy .Range("A1")
        .Range("N1:O1").Formula = Array("art/qty/date", "controle")
         
        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("N2:N" & Lastrow).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-6]&"" "",""QTY ""&RC[-4]&"" ""," & _
               "TEXT(RC[-2],""dd-mm-jj""))"
        .Range("O2:O" & Lastrow).Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF(R2C14:R2000C14,RC[-1])=1,0,1)"
        .Columns("A:O").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        
        With .Range("A1:O" & Lastrow)
            .Sort Key1:=.Range("N1"), Header:=xlYes
            ws.Sort.Apply
            
            .AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="1a"
            
            ' check any data
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rng = .Range("N2:N" & Lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "No rows to color", vbExclamation
                Exit Sub
            End If
            
            ' visible cells only
            For Each cell In rng
                
                If cell.Value <> prev Then
                    bSwitch = Not bSwitch
                End If
                
                If bSwitch Then
                    cell.EntireRow.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
                Else
                    cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(226, 226, 226)
                End If
                prev = cell.Value
                
            Next
        End With
    End With
   
End Sub
```

Comment: This also works like a charm, just a tiny typo in the autofield filter, I changed criteria to 1 and it works like it should, so thanks for your time to help me :)

Comment: @shaye The 1a was test for no data, I forgot to restore.